# Problem excluding subdirectories after including their parent in Duplicity

Tags: backup, duplicity

I am backing up with something very similar to the below:

```
/usr/bin/duplicity (irrelevant options) \
  --include /home/me \
  --exclude /home/me/example \
  ssh://remote/backupjar
```

The problem I have is that the excluded `example` subdirectory is being included in my backups. Even after explicitly giving an option to exclude it. The output shows:

```
A: /home/me
A: /home/me/otherstuff
A: /home/me/example
A: /hmoe/me/example/undesired-file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to put the exclude first.  The documentation, section
[File Selection](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect10)
says:

> Each file selection condition either matches or doesn’t match a given file. A given file is excluded by the file selection system **exactly when the first matching file selection condition** specifies that the file be excluded; otherwise the file is included.

In your example, `/home/me/example` will be matched by `--include /home/me` first, causing the exclude to be ignored.